# Javascript optional parameters for callbacks

Tags: javascript

I want to do something like `$.ajax()` success and error callbacks.

This is what I have so far:

```
var FileManager = {
            LoadRequiredFiles: function (onLoadingCallback, onCompleteCallback) {
                //Not sure what to do here
                this.OnLoading = onLoadingCallback;
                this.OnCompleteCallback = onCompleteCallback;

                this.OnLoading();
                this.OnComplete();
            },
            OnLoading: function () {
                //empty by default
            }
            OnComplete: function () {
                //empty by default
            }

};
//I want to do something like this:
FileManager.LoadRequiredFiles({OnLoading: function() {
            alert('loading');
       }
});
```

How do I fix this up properly? I'm using `FileManager` as my namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the functions are defined:

```
var FileManager = {
    LoadRequiredFiles: function (config) {
        config = config || {};
        this.OnLoading = config.onLoadingCallback;
        this.OnCompleteCallback = config.onCompleteCallback;

        if(typeof this.OnLoading =='function') {
            this.OnLoading();
        }

        //Or use the shortcut:
        if(this.OnComplete) {
            this.OnComplete();
        }
    }
};

FileManager.LoadRequiredFiles(
    {
        onLoadingCallback: function() {
            alert('loading');
       }
    }
);
```

Comment: How about setting up the parameters? I have no idea if what I did was correct, to match up with how I want to be able to call the method.